# OpenMP specify thread number of a for loop iteration

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm using the following command to parallelize a single loop over the available threads of the program:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads)
for(long i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    array[i] = calculateStuff(i,...);
}
```

For technical reasons, I would like to guarantee that thread number 0 executes `i=0`, and thread number 1 executes `i=1`. In other words, I want always `i=omp_get_thread_num()`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) schedule(static,1)
```

Now that @Hristo Iliev has turned up I'm 100% confident that the OpenMP standard requires the static schedule to assign iteration 0 to thread 0, 1 to 1, *etc*.

Try it and let us know how you get on.

Then again

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) schedule(dynamic,1)
```

ought to work too, since you only have as many iterations as you have threads.  It's possible though that if thread 0 finishes its work before thread `n` starts then thread 0 will grab iteration `n`.

Comment: I think you're right. Apparently openmp does that by default. I had a mistake in my program that made me not see this. Thank you.

Comment: §2.7.1 Loop Construct: "When `schedule(static, chunk_size)` is specified, iterations are divided
into chunks of size `chunk_size`, and the chunks are assigned to the threads in the team in a round-robin fashion in the order of the thread number." I.e. the standard does require it.

Answer (score 5):

Using a loop is a waste of resources in that particular case. Simply use `omp_get_thread_num()`:

```
#include <omp.h>

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads)
{
    int i = omp_get_thread_num();
    array[i] = calculateStuff(i,...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm gonna do this, but I can't choose this as correct answer as this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It's not a an answer but more a suggestion to improve your code. Sometimes I wish that comments on Stack Overflow could be a bit more elaborate when it comes to formatting.